# Over time Application built in FlashBuilder runs slower and slower

Tags: performance, actionscript, flash-builder, slowdown

I have an application built in FlashBuilder written in actionscript that when I launch the application its very responsive and smooth running.  However, over time and after interacting with some sliders in the application the program slowly becomes more and more unresponsive and less smooth.  For instance, when changing the slider's value from 0 to 100 it will update the slider with many values between the end value 100.  However, after the application has been running for a while when taking the same action of 0 to 100 and moving the slider at the same rate from 0 to 100 I might only get a handful of values instead of maybe 50.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I should check to reduce this leakage of performance?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you most definitely have a memory leak in your application. If you are using **Flash Builder/Flex Builder**, you can use the **Profiler** tool to find out when exactly the memory usage increases and what objects are not being garbage collected.

Just make sure that you are not creating new instances every time the slider moves. Also remember that event listeners should be removed as soon as they are no longer needed.

This bit of documentation was rather helpful to me when I had a similar problem:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=profiler_7.html

Comment: So I ran the Profiler tool that you mentioned.  The peak memory and current memory stay the same throughout the slowdown.  The only Class that builds up Cumulative Instances is the MethodClosure Class in the builtin.as$0 package.  The buildup of these instances is pretty slow though (I'm at 6k right now), so I'm not sure whether I should be concerned or not.  It did confirm that only two instances of the slider is being created, which is correct since I have two sliders on the screen to play with.